# Google web starter kit gulp serve error

Tags: node.js, gulp, google-web-starter-kit

I want to start using Google web starter kit.
I installed node, ruby, gulp and npm

```
C:\Users\Greg>node -v
v4.1.1

C:\Users\Greg>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\Greg>npm -v
2.14.4

C:\Users\Greg>gulp -v
[13:48:29] CLI version 3.9.0
```

I installed in my repository:

```
cd my-project
npm install
npm install gulp -g
```

When i use `gulp serve` in command line i have error

```
C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Web development\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\my-project>gulp serv
e
[13:35:46] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Web development\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\my-pro
ject\gulpfile.js
[13:35:46] Starting 'styles'...
[13:35:48] **'styles' errored after 1.63 s**
[13:35:48] Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at getBinding (C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Web development\web-starter-kit-0.5.4\m
y-project\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Web development\web-starter-kit
-0.5.4\my-project\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:188
:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Web development\web-      starter-kit
-0.5.4\my-project\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
```

What is wrong?
How can i see it on my local server with browser sync? When i'm typing localhost:3000 in my browser nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

Try using node 0.12 (which is the previous version). Node 4 just came out, and some modules might not work with libsass being one of those ones.

Comment: Ok, this worked, now i don't have error. I have question what should happen when i type gulp serve in the command line. It will open the project in the browser automatically? When i open index file i face only html without CSS. Why?